How can I prevent Qt Modality from interacting with external application windows?
I seem to be running into an issue where the modality of Qt dialogs is affecting the z-index of other grandparents.
A minimal reproducible example is the following,
from PyQt6.QtCore import pyqtSignal, Qt
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QLabel, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout


class DialogA(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowModality(Qt.WindowModality.ApplicationModal)
        self.setModal(True)
        self.setWindowTitle("Dialog A")
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(QLabel("This is Dialog A"))

        open_dialog_b_button = QPushButton("Open Dialog B")
        open_dialog_b_button.clicked.connect(self.open_dialog_b)

        self.layout().addWidget(open_dialog_b_button)

    def open_dialog_b(self):
        dialog_b = DialogB(self)
        dialog_b.closed.connect(self.close_dialog_a)
        dialog_b.exec()

    def close_dialog_a(self):
        self.deleteLater()


class DialogB(QDialog):
    closed = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowModality(Qt.WindowModality.ApplicationModal)
        self.setModal(True)
        self.setWindowTitle("Dialog B")
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(QLabel("This is Dialog B"))
        close_button = QPushButton("Close")
        close_button.clicked.connect(self.on_close_button_clicked)
        self.layout().addWidget(close_button)

    def on_close_button_clicked(self):
        self.closed.emit()
        self.deleteLater()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.closed.emit()
        super().closeEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    main_window = QDialog()
    main_window.setWindowTitle("Main Window")
    main_window.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())

    open_dialog_a_button = QPushButton("Open Dialog A")
    open_dialog_a_button.clicked.connect(lambda: DialogA(main_window).show())

    main_window.layout().addWidget(open_dialog_a_button)
    main_window.show()
    app.exec()

Running the following code will create one MainWindow dialog which creates DialogA and DialogA will create DialogB. When DialogB is closed via the button being closed, it seems to push the MainWindow one window backwards. Therefore, any Window behind the MainWindow will become infront of the MainWindow. The last focused window seems to be important, as I am running PyCharm that is my last focused window. It is then easy to run via PyCharm and have PyCharm as my example window that comes into the foreground when closing DialogB.
To reproduce it, run the code above and interact close DialogB with the last focused window on the OS behind the MainWindow. When closing, the MainWindow will go behind the last focused window.
The structure here is mimicking the code structure in my much larger codebase, i.e. I need deleteLater and have noticed that this is resolved using .close instead.
My goal here is to understand, given the current code structure, why the MainWindow would be going behind the last focused window when closing DialogB.

If the problem is solved with close(), then what's the point of forcing deleteLater()? I've already explained that you can just set the proper WA_DeleteOnClose attribute, which deletes the window after being closed.

This is a small and reproducible example of what replicates a much larger codebase. When dialogs are closed, this uses deleteLater and I cannot change it to close. I tried, but things went south real quick.

My goal is to try and understand why the MainWindow z-index would change due to children closing from the current setup.

With all due respect, the example and its explanation are partial and inaccurate, especially since you do not clarify why you must use deleteLater() instead of close(). Calling close() properly calls the underlying platform functions that allow Qt to "keep up" with its own window ordering and the OS one instead of completely delegating it to the OS management, which seems the issue here. We don't know what you "tried" as you didn't provide a more appropriate [mre] that more closely relates to your issue, so we cannot help you with that. That said, as a general rule, when dealing with »

» the possibility of "nested" modal dialogs, exec() should be avoided at all (as the docs clearly warn about), and open() should be used instead, with appropriate object lifespan detection and related signal connections; this can avoid known issues related to nested event loops, which should always be avoided as they may cause unexpected behavior, just like in your case. So, please clarify what your real issue is, because it seems to me (also considering your previous post) that you're dealing with an XY problem, »

» which is asking the wrong question for the wrong problem. Explain in detail why you need to use deleteLater() as opposed to close(), also adding a more appropriately related MRE carefully crafted for that purpose, so that we may be able to help you with that, instead of trying to fix something that shouldn't be addressed to begin with.

I was reading the documentation and deleteLater serves a better purpose compared to close as it actually deletes the dialog. close allows the possibility to call show in the future. I was able to reproduce it again but deleteLater does seem to actually be the cause.

I created another reproducible case in where if I have 4 dialogs, A, B, C and D. Where A and B are children of C and C is a child of D. I changed the deleteLater order to be A -> C -> B and it seems that this changes the window ordering so that D changes window ordering. If I change the ordering to A -> B -> C (deleteLater is called on all children first) then it's OK.

I'm not sure I'm following you. Note that if a parent is set for deletion, the result is that each one of children are recursively set for deletion as well, recursively, and before their parents; this means that a parent will eventually be deleted only once all its children have been. Also, having sibling dialogs (dialogs that have a common direct parent) is not only an uncommon pattern, but also a confusing one, both for the window manager and to the user. You should probably rethink your parent/child hierarchy: a dialog window should always have a unique hierarchy role.
